# build failed after flutter upgrade

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

When upgrade flutter has an exception and the application can't run again how can I solve it?

```
In file included from
    /Users/raitotec/developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.12+4/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.m:5:
    /Users/raitotec/developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.12+4/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h:5:9
    : fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


flutter doctor -v


[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H524 darwin-x64, locale en-SA)
    • Flutter version 1.22.5 at /Users/raitotec/developer/flutter
    • Framework revision 7891006299 (9 months ago), 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800
    • Engine revision ae90085a84
    • Dart version 2.10.4

  [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/raitotec/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 50.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 12 mini (mobile) • A9648508-3B05-4468-B593-477288FC7370 • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-4 (simulator)
```

Answer (score 0):

try `flutter clean` then `flutter pub upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue.
After `pub upgrade`, (long story short) the app was not working as before.

The file **pubspec.yaml** contains the dependencies(packages) used by the app, usually  the min version of the added packages.
The file **pubspec.lock**, contains **all** the dependencies(packages) of the app, with the exact version of each dependency.

When you run `pub upgrade` it fetches the newest versions of all the dependencies and updates the pubspec.lock,
so for example, a dependency in pubspec.yaml may states version 1.0, after the `pub upgrade` the used version can be 1.1(in the pubspec.lock)
Although this file should not included in the commits, if you have access to the previous version of it, you can compare it with the one after the pub upgrade` and revert it where needed.

Downgrading a dependency solved the problem for me.